# iOS application upload after rejection

Tags: ios, app-store, webdav

I forgot provide demo account information login and password, and my application was rejected with message:

> .... While your iTunes Connect Application State will still show as
>   Rejected, we don't require a new binary for this type of issue. Please
>   visit iTunes Connect, Manage Your Applications, revise the appropriate
>   metadata values or settings, then click "Submit New Metadata"

I add required information to metadata reviews note. But i have not found "Submit New Metadata". I click "ready upload" button, and now application status "Waiting For Upload"
When i try upload application binary from XCode 3.2.4 i have a errors:

> An error occured while processing the http request for the webDAV
>   upload  An exception has occured:401 Unauthorized

Questions how fix this erorr?
And where is "Waiting For Upload" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the weekend I tried again to upload binary and upload was successfull. After 5 minutes the application status has changed to "In review". I used mac os on virtual machine and reboot only vm. Maybe computer(not vm) reboot decided the problem or maybe error was in itunes side.

Comment: Thanks ! I had this kind of Webdav problem, and a simple reboot resolved it :)

Answer (score 1):

> we don't require a new binary for this type of issue

You should not upload new binary. You should just find button "Submit New Metadata" and press it after demo data was entered in Review Notes.

Comment: But i am click "ready upload" button and status changed from rejected to "Waiting For Upload" but in answer  `While your iTunes Connect Application State will still show as Rejected, we don't require a new binary for this type of issue.` And i thought the button has disappeared, if of course it was before.

Comment: You should not click `Upload new binary`.

Comment: There's no button "Upload new binary". What should i do now, i can't load new binary. I try use application loader and have same errors.

Comment: But what if in order to resolve the issue that caused the rejection a new version is in fact the best (or even only) option?  Apple may not "require" a new binary version, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the developer doesn't need to submit one anyways.  I don't think it's correct to say that the developer "shouldn't" upload a new binary just because Apple said they don't require one.